# Uniquely identify an item's element in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

can you help me how to find a certain item's textView. For example I have a listView with some items and every item is made of 3 textViews (name, price, description). Now I want to change the value of the "price" textView with and updateView(int index) method. How do I identify the correct textView in the correct item?

Let's say i have 5 items (product1, ..., product5).
now i want to update the price of the 3rd product (product3).
I call `updateView(3)`
My updateView(int index) method so far

```
private void updateView(int index){
    // thats how I get the row
    View v = lvProduct.getChildAt(index); 
    // now I want to find the tvPrice in that row
    // but I'm not sure how to go about this
}
```

any tips would be great :D

Comment: Why don't you update the datasource and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter?

Comment: the problem is that when i try to do that uising findViewById(R.id.tvPrice) it updates the tvPrice of the 1st item every time and it seems I can't quite control it...all I need is a way to identify which tvPrice is in the 1st item, which is in the 2nd and so on and then be able to call that specific tvPrice and then call like `setText()` on that textview...or did I miss something

Comment: There is an easier method than that doing all that. Let the ListView do the working for you. Just change the datasource, your ArrayList or whatever you are using as the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally approach this would be to do the following:

- Create a model for your list item (now days people prefer to use RecyclerView) - the model of course will have the fields/variables representing what you want to be displayed (like 3 Strings).
- Now, to actually keep track of the item a user clicked, I can simply get the id of that item ( column of the table storing this item in the database) by calling a custom method in my adapter like getItem(int position) which returns an actual item.
- That getItem method will return me an item with a getId() getter method.
- Notice now that when you are creating your list items to pass to your custom adapter, your list item model MUST expect an (id) value in its constructor because that is how you will be able to access the actual value in your table to edit.
- So then you query your table using your clicked item's id and update it and simply update the view automatically through your adapter.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but here is the catch, im not using `onClick` method at all, I send the new price (along with the id of the row it affects) via GCM and catch it with a `BroadcastReceiver`. And yes I did make my own CustomAdapter and it gets a `layoutResource` (with three textViews) in the constructor but I still dont understand how I can access the tv-s inside the item and would really appreciate if you could provide me with an example (I'm not that experienced in android development) Thank you very much for taking the time to help.